# Passing 0 arguments to variadic macro fails in GCC, but only in C++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, macros, clang

In the following code, `CHOOSE_MACRO` is supposed to select between 2 macros that are passed to it, based on the number of arguments: `FOO()` should expand to `RESULT0`, and `FOO(x)` should expand to `RESULT1`.

This works with Clang for both C (http://rextester.com/LRX65441) and C++ (http://rextester.com/FYC46680).

In GCC, it works for C code (http://rextester.com/VWAPR56841), but in C++ code ***both invocations produce `RESULT1`*** (http://rextester.com/ZNEKAV71986).

What's going on, and how can I make this work in a cross-platform manner?

```
#define CHOOSE_MACRO(_0, _1, NAME, ...) NAME
#define FOO(...) CHOOSE_MACRO(~~, ##__VA_ARGS__, RESULT1, RESULT0)

void foo()
{
    FOO();  // should produce RESULT0  -  actually produces RESULT1 for gcc -x c++
}

void bar()
{
    FOO(x); // should produce RESULT1
}
```

Comment: It seems me that standards is omisse about this (`##__VA_ARGS__`) construction, so g++ implement it as an extension. So, in order to get your results, pass an `-std=gnu++14` option. See here: [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ewx9GqHCrLnwpvp9)

Comment: Sure it's an extension, but ostensibly both these compilers support it, so I'm just trying to understand why it doesn't work. It's possible (though annoying) to work around too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply mistaken.  I enhanced your code a little and tried it on many different C++ compilers, and it works the way you want every single time.

See here: https://godbolt.org/g/D6rgxS

Comment: Interesting. Adding `-std=c++0x` changes the result. I assume the default is `gnu++0x`.